# How to create different interfaces views between me and clients in Netlogo Hubnet, by hidding information in the client's view only?

Tags: netlogo, hubnet

I am modelling a game on pest monitoring using Netlogo hubnet. The model takes the form of a simulator where specialized agents evolve in an environment in search of pest outbreaks. The clients (players of my game) make decision with the few environmental informations they have.

I would like to hide some information to the clients (agents or patches information that won't appear in their view) while still being able to observe them on my own view. For instance, I would like to make plant-agents or rain-agents to appear but only on my view.

The *display* doesn't help since it is an observer primitive.
Using the *hide-turtle* with *hubnet-send* don't work neither cause it hides agents on my view as well.

Any ideas? Is that even doable on Netlogo hubnet?

Comment: I've not used them so I cannot leave a full answer, but have you checked out [the "Customizing the client's view" section](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/hubnet-authoring.html#customizing-the-clients-view) of the manual?  Specifically [`hubnet-send-override`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#hubnet-send-override) sounds like it might help.  There is a Client Overrides Example HubNet model that comes with NetLogo, along with Critter Designers HubNet, Current in a Wire HubNet, and MTG 1 Equal Opportunities HubNet that all use the prim you might check out.